# Color barplot in R based on a fixed scale

Tags: r, dataframe, bar-chart

I have a dataframe in R with three columns, `label` indicates the x-axis label, `values` would indicate the bar height for a barplot, and and a `color` value. For instance:

```
    label     value       color
1  Label1 0.9645477 0.434680035
2  Label2 1.0816859 0.070992644
3  Label3 1.0043559 0.923586653
4  Label4 1.0065987 0.884469520
5  Label5        NA          NA
6  Label6 0.9537397 0.307786218
```

I'd like to make a bar plot of the values where the bars are colored by the value in the color column. The color column always ranges from 0 to 1 and I'd like to make discrete colors, on a green to red spectrum, for bins `0-0.05, 0-0.1, etc.` And then I'd like to have a legend associated with the barplot. For the cases of NA, I'd like there to just be an empty spot on the plot with no bar.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the `ggplot2` library:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dataframe) + geom_bar(aes(x=label, y = value, fill = color), stat = "identity")
```

the `aes` parameter defines the mapping within geom_bar, using `fill = color` will fill the bars based on the `color` column in your dataframe (setting the color parameter will change the outline of the bars, not the fill). The stat parameter outside of aes defines whether geom_bar computes a histogram or a barchart.